# why routes with auth middleware don't open after Auth::attempt in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

my login page don't go anywhere, just reload login page after press login!

in the loginController I don't have login method :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/
public function username()
{
    return 'phone';
}

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
 public function login (AdminLoginRequest $request){
    $credentials = $request->only('phone', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        if (Auth::user()->role == 'user'){
            Session::flush();
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('login');
        }
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.index') ;
    }
}
}
```

and in my web.php routes are :

```
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')->prefix('dashboard')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {
Route::get('/index', function () {
    echo 'hi there';
})->name('dashboard.index');
});
```

route dashboard.index never run if middleware is auth, without auth middleware it is ok!

why after attempt we don't have auth authorization ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Does your blade have the error displays? This usually happens when an input has a validation error. Try `@dump($errors->all())` on your login view to check.

Comment: I test it, there is no error

Comment: You didn't change `RouteServiceProvider::HOME`?

Comment: public const HOME = '/dashboard/index';